# I want the game over screen on this super mario bros C++ remake to trigger arduino/batch file

Tags: c++

I found a someone who has listed the source code in C++ for their remake of Super Mario and I would like to know how I could edit the code for the "Game over screen" to trigger my Arduino or batch file (which ever is easier). The link to this source code is below. I'm pretty new but am every interested in getting this done. Any information would help. Thank you so much!

[Github project link](https://github.com/MitchellSternke/SuperMarioBros-C)

Comment: Are you able to make this code run by yourself? Are you familiar with c++ development? How do you usually start this batch file? How do you usually trigger your Arduino?

Comment: I'll be honest I haven't tried it yet. But even if this doesn't work for this this specific mario game I'm very interested in getting a certain event in another C++ game of another person's or of my own creation. Curious about how I go about it

Comment: I am brand new to C++ and am taking on a very big, 1st arduino project but am committed to making this work. I've played with batch files before but just simple tasks that I've set in scheduler or manually run. Any advice would help.

Comment: Looks like you're after something like the [`system`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) function. Please start working on your project and try this. Then come back to us when you encounter a snag. The format of this Q&A site is not well suited for "how do I start this project" type of question, and for beginner c++ questions in general.

Comment: This is not a remake in C++. This is an automatically generated disassembly of the original assembler code.